# Azure Websites 500 Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service, internal-server-error

I've deployed several websites to azure websites previously without a problem. I always add the elmah nuget package because it make diagnosing issues easier. However, I'm currently stuck with http://yis3.azurewebsites.net

When I try to reach the site I get an http 500 error. I've tried following the suggestions from this page [msdn](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio/) but I've hit the following problems:

1. Will not load symbols when I attach debugger. I've ensured site is    compiled and published as debug
2. Despite enabling tracing and    selecting "View Streaming Logs in Output Window" all I get in the    VS2013 output window is "Now new trace in the past 1 mins, 2 mins    etc"

The website uses EF6 to connect to a SQL Express database. I've checked the connection strings in the web.config and websites portal - they look ok. I guess the site is failing before trying to reach the database though - the /home/documents action should return a view with hard-coded html and even that fails!

I have checked the website is configured to run .Net v4.5
Could anyone please advise what else I can try?

Comment: In your web.config, disable custom errors as well as ensure that the compliation is running in debug mode.  Try and force the site to give you the yellow screen of death, which should include the stack trace

Comment: This looks like an error in the web.config - in VS2013 click on the Web.debug.config and "Preview Transform" - then copy that and try running with the generated web.config.  You can also FTP into your deployed website files and just download the generated web.cong for comparison.

Comment: Many thanks viperguynaz. I wasn't aware of the preview transform option and this highlighted the problem for me. If you add your comment as an answer then I'll mark it as correct.